# change a div class with JS and an event listener

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to simply change the class of a div with an event listener, but it returns:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null.

Html code:

```
<div class="menuList" > 

  

...(rest of the menu, 145 lines of html, no mistake) 

  

<button class="menuHamburger menuListElementButton"> 

    <a href="" class="reducedMenubutton"> &#9776;</a> 

</button>
```

Javascript:

```js
document.querySelector('.reducedMenubutton').addEventListener('click',classMenu); 

function classMenu() { 
   const $class= document.querySelector('.menuList'); 
   $class.classList.replace("menuList","menuListVertical"); 
};
```

The function is working but i don't see why the onclick doesn't.
I look for a solution for hours. Any clue is welcome

Comment: Why do you have a `<a>` inside a `<button>` ? You should get rid of the `<a>` and add the eventlistener to the button instead.

Comment: Your code should work. Just wrap your code inside a DOMContentLoaded  event and the error should dissapear.

Comment: @Amaury Hanser I did it and it works now! thanks